# Need some help understanding the syntax of this function

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Was following a tutorial and while making sure i am understanding everything i am doing. i am currently unable to understand the syntax used to select sliderCurrent sliderAbove or slider below. would appreciate the help i understand what it does but not necessarily  how it does it.

```
for (var i=25;i>0;i--){
    let slider = document.createElement('div');
    slider.setAttribute('class', 'slider animate');
    slider.setAttribute('id','slider'+i)
    document.getElementById('game').append(slider);
}

function stopSliding(slider){
    var sliderCurrent = document.getElementById('slider'+(slider))
    var sliderAbove = document.getElementById('slider'+(slider+1))
    var sliderBelow = document.getElementById('slider'+ (slider-1 ))
    var left = window.getComputedStyle(sliderCurrent).getPropertyValue(left);
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the comments for explanation.

```
/**
* This a loop. It loops 25 times.
* At each iteration, it creates a div, applies a class and an id to this div.
* Finally, it appends each div inside the element with the id "game".
*/
for (vari=25;i>0;i--){
    let slider = document.createElement('div'); // <-- should use "const" instead of "let".
    slider.setAttribute('class', 'slider animate');
    slider.setAttribute('id','slider'+i)
    document.getElementById('game').append(slider);
}

/**
* This function stops a slider.
* The argument "slider" is probably referring to the id of a slider created in the loop. You should rename the argument to "slider_id" to make it easier to understand.
* 1. "sliderCurrent", is the slider you are trying to stop (created in the loop).
* 2. "sliderAbove" and "sliderBelow" are the sliders before and after the one you are trying to stop.
* 3. "left" is the left css property of "sliderCurrent". This works by using the "getComputedStyle()" JavaScript function that returns an object containing all CSS properties of an element. Then, the "getPropertyValue" returns the "left" value inside the object, giving you something like : "left : 32px".
*/
function stopSliding(slider){
    var sliderCurrent = document.getElementById('slider'+(slider))
    var sliderAbove = document.getElementById('slider'+(slider+1))
    var sliderBelow = document.getElementById('slider'+ (slider-1 ))
    var left = window.getComputedStyle(sliderCurrent).getPropertyValue(left); // ...getPropertyValue("left"), "left" needs to be inside apostrophes.
}
```

Here is an improved version of your code snippet (using "const" instead of "let" and "var", and using, etc).

```
// Create divs and appends the create elements to an element with id of "game".
for (const i = 25; i > 0; i--){
    const slider = document.createElement('div');
    
    slider.setAttribute('class', 'slider animate');
    slider.setAttribute('id', `slider${i}`);
    document.getElementById('game').append(slider);
}

// Stop a slider
function stopSliding(slider_id){
    const sliderCurrent = document.getElementById(`slider${slider_id}`);
    const sliderAbove = document.getElementById(`slider${slider_id+1}`)
    const sliderBelow = document.getElementById(`slider${slider_id-1}`)
    const leftCSSValue = window.getComputedStyle(sliderCurrent).getPropertyValue("left");
}
```